# ¿Cómo habilito Scala en NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, scala

Ya tengo instalado el Scala, le puse los plugins de Scala a NetBeans, pero me sigue dando un error cuando intento compilar el proyecto en Scala.

Intento compilar esto:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
```

En el Output me sale:

> Compiling 1 source file to D:\Alejandro\Proyectos\Java\NetBeans\Scal
>   de Pruepa\build\classes D:\Alejandro\Proyectos\Java\NetBeans\Scal de
>   Pruepa\nbproject\build-impl.xml:405: The following error occurred
>   while executing this line: D:\Alejandro\Proyectos\Java\NetBeans\Scal
>   de Pruepa\nbproject\build-impl.xml:238: bad option: '-make:transitive'

Y además me sale un cartel de excepción que dice:

> A java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception has occurred. Please report
>   this at http://www.netbeans.org/community/issues.html, including a
>   copy of your messages.log file as an attachment. The messages.log file
>   is located in your
>   C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\var\log folder.

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar el error que ves cuando intentas compilar? A menudo, los mensajes de error proporcionan información que ayuda a solucionarlo. De ser posible incluye un __[mcve]__ que permita reproducir tu error.

Comment: ¿Versión de scala y versión del plugin?

Comment: Aparte de instalar los plugins directamente del Netbeans ¿Descargastes Scala de la pagina oficial? y ¿agregastes el path para scala? Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

A partir de scala 2.11, ya no está soportado el argumento `'-make:transitive'`.

Elimina `'-make:transitive'` de los parámetros para `scalac` (*Files view > ScalaApplication > nbproject > build-impl.xml*).

Te recomiendo que uses algo más moderno que el plugin para netbeans si quieres desarrollar en [scala](/questions/tagged/scala).